# HttpClient - Avoid NetworkStream Disposed Exception

Tags: c#, networking, httpclient

I've came across a quite weird thing when using HttpClient. Basically, if I use the client like once and then wait a bit (1m15) it will throw an exception which is automatically handled. Here's the full error:

```
4/23/2023 8:49:58 PM | [Error] Caused by System.Private.CoreLib | Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream'.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowObjectDisposedException(Object instance)
```

As you can see in the stacktrace there's nothing related to the code I've written.
And here's my own code in case:

```cs
s_HttpClient = new HttpClient
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri(Configuration.EndpointAddress),
    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
};

try
{
    response = await client.SendAsync(request);
}
catch (Exception ex) when (ex is HttpRequestException || ex is TaskCanceledException)
{
   response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
}
```

Minimal example:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += (sender, e) =>
     {
         Console.WriteLine(e.Exception.ToString());
     };

     Test();

     while (true);
}

static async Task Test()
{
     HttpClient client = new HttpClient
     {
         BaseAddress = new Uri("https://google.com")
     };

     HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "/search?q=stackoverflow");
     HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();

     try
     {
          var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
          Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
     }
}
```

Is there a way to avoid this exception? Or is it a bug?

Comment: Any chance to get a full example that we can run locally on our own machine?

Comment: I've edited my question, I guess that should do. @Oliver

Comment: It's quite normal, it's just the result of connection pooling (the connection gets closed after some time or reused if it's still open.

Comment: I don't think so though, it's not "normal", an exception shouldn't be thrown in the first place, everything should be executed without any exceptions otherwise you would just send a log message if it's really "normal."

Comment: Your "minimal example" does not produce any error for me (after making it compilable). Also `async void` looks suspicious.

Comment: Well you aren't disposing the `response` so that might have something to do with it also.

Comment: @Charlieface I do dispose both the request and response afterwards.

Comment: @GuruStron in my code I use "public static async Task [...]" I guess I should change to to Task instead of void in my question.